# calling a method in objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm trying to learn objective c. I have xcode 4 and am reading my way through a beginners book on how to make iphone applications.

I can code c sharp reasonable well but c is obviously lower level and involves a fair bit of memory management so I think that's where i'm falling down here.

Anyway, I am trying to create a method of return type double. In c sharp I would write this as

```
public double test()
{
    return 12;
}
```

I then want to be able to call my method from another method. Here's part of what I've been working on so far.

```
- (double)test
{
    return 1985;
}

- (IBAction)btnConvert_Click:(id)sender
{
    double str = [double test];

    NSString *hello = txtAmount.text;
    double myDouble = [hello doubleValue] * exrate;
    lblResult.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.2f", str];
}
```

It throws up an error where I try to establish the double method str "expected expression". What I'd like to do is to pass in myDouble to test, then to do some calculations and then return the value.

How would I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `double str = [double test];` you should write `double str = [self test];` since you are calling a method of your own class, not on `double`

Comment: That worked. Thank you! Just a quick question. How would I pass in a double to method test?

Comment: `- (double)testWithParameter:(double)param { ... }` would be your method. You can call it by `[self testWithParameter:myDoubleValue];`

Comment: oh I see. I changed the method to - (double)test:(double)xval and used test:80

Answer (score 2):

Use as shown below

```
double str = [self test];
```

Comment: @codemonkey: Always stuck to cocoa-naming conventions, this will make your code readable. And try to use wrapper classes as much as possible. as NSInteger, NSNumber instead of int etc.

Comment: Thank you. What are the cocoa-naming conventions?

Comment: btnConvert_Click should be convert: & str coudld be doubleValue & txtAmount should be amount.

Comment: http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000082.php , https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html , http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/method-names-in-objective-c.html

Comment: Ok. I guess it's because I've been coding with .net for so long. Thank you for your help, i'll try and do that from now on.

Comment: No problem, even I faced a lot from VB to C/C++ then to Cococa, even i was prompt to use txtFirstName, bttnOk, lstTable, cmbStatus etc... :)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to call `[self test]` to invoke your method