# Method declaration in Objective-C: use of undefined method

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm junior in Objective-c. Now I've some difficulties with method declaration.
I've been created my own method:

```
- (BOOL)updateLocation:(CLLocation *)userLocation fromLocationPoint:(CLLocation *)locationPoint ifMaxDistance:(float)maxDistance
{
    if([userLocation distanceFromLocation:locationPoint] >= maxDistance){
        return YES;
    }else{
        return NO;
    }
}
```

But when I try to call it via `[updateLocation ...]`, Xcode says me: "Use of undefined method updateLocation". What's wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [calling a method in objective c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14082407/calling-a-method-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `[self updateLocation...]` to call the method in the same class (file)

Comment: I agree and think the OP did forget the self

Answer (score 0):

Please declare the method in .h file as

```
- (BOOL)updateLocation:(CLLocation *)userLocation fromLocationPoint:(CLLocation *)locationPoint ifMaxDistance:(float)maxDistance;
```

Then you will be able to access the function